# Why can't I correctly assign variables to an Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, digits

So I'm writing a program that inputs a number (binary) then assigns each digit of that input into an array.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Please enter a binary number: ");
    String input = Console.ReadLine();
    int inputLength = input.Length;
    int nInput = Convert.ToInt32(input);
    int[] digits;
    digits = new int[inputLength];

    int remain = 10;
    int divider = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i > inputLength; i++)
    {
        digits[i] = (nInput % remain) / divider;
        remain = remain * 10;
        divider = divider * 10;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Demo number  " + digits[0]);
}
```

However, it seems like all my arrays have a value of 0, whenever I run the code. Why is that?

So if my input is 11010,
`digit[0]` should be 0.
`digit[1]` should be 1.
`digit[2]` should be 0. 
`digit[3]` should be 1.
`digit[4]` should be 1.

Comment: `i > inputLength` should be `i < inputLength` for starters.

Comment: Hey, next time debug your code. You'll find the problem yourself faster than posting a question ;-)

Comment: int inputLength = Convert.ToInt32(input);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Loop is not executing since its condition always false; So you are getting its default value, change the condition as `i < inputLength;`

If you do so and give the input as "123"

The output on the console will be : `Demo number  3`; And the array Will be

```
digit[0]=3
digit[1]=2
digit[2]=1
```

**Few suggestions to improve your code:**

- use `int.TryParse();` instead for `Convert.ToInt32();` for avoid throwing conversion exceptions. you can see a comparison [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/845439/Difference-between-int-Parse-Convert-ToInt-and-int)
- Since the numbers are in an array you can reverse them using [`Array.Reverse()`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-reverse)

That is ..

```
        String input =Console.ReadLine();
        int nInput;
        int inputLength = input.Length;
        if (int.TryParse(input, out nInput))
        {
            int[] digits = new int[inputLength];
            Array.Reverse(digits);
            Console.WriteLine("Reversed Number is:{0}",String.Join( "",digits));
        }
        else { Console.WriteLine("Wrong input"); }
```

Comment: Yes thank you, it works now! I overlooked such a small thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int[] vec = new int[input.Length]; 
            int i = 0;
            foreach (char ch in input) {
                vec[i] = Convert.ToInt32(ch.ToString());
                i++;
            }

            foreach (int numaux in vec) {
                Console.WriteLine(numaux);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Just iterate over the input string using foreach statement (Will save you from the error that was already pointed out) and convert each char into an int that will be stored inside of the array.

Cheers!